# Pod push fails to push to master repo

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to release a podspec on Cocoapods. According to the documentation, I should be able to use `pod spec create [NAME]` followed by `rake release` to release the podspec. Everything seems to go fine until `rake release` tries to push to the Specs repo.

```
Adding the spec to the `master' repo

  $ /opt/local/bin/git status --porcelain 2>&1
 - [No change] IPQuickModal (0.1.2)

Pushing the `master' repo

Username for 'https://github.com': brightredchilli
Password for 'https://brightredchilli@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/'
```

It looks like it is trying to push to the main Cocoapods Spec repo, which will make sense as to why it fails. Am I missing something? It looks like the tool is easy to use, but I need push access to the spec repo. However, this is not clear on the [doc page](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit a podspec to CocoaPods (currently) you must submit a pull request to the [specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs). Currently no one but the core team has push access.

Comment: Thanks @MishieMoo, if I may add some two cents here, it would be really nice if the rake release tool was modified so that it does not do the push by default, and make the docs clearer about how to submit a PR. I could do a documentation PR.